# Hibernate : More than one table found: table_name

Tags: hibernate

I am using Hibernate 5.x in my project. when the application is starting up i get the following message continuously and my app does not start.
the human readable part is `"More than one table found: t_agent"` sentence.

> org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.@156:   HHH000400: Using dialect:
>   org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
>   org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry.register@138:  HHH000270: Type
>   registration [byte[]] overrides previous :
>   org.hibernate.type.BinaryType@149b53fa
>   org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry.register@138:  HHH000270: Type
>   registration [[B] overrides previous :
>   org.hibernate.type.BinaryType@149b53fa
>   org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry.register@138:  HHH000270: Type
>   registration [Byte[]] overrides previous :
>   org.hibernate.type.WrapperBinaryType@638977e0
>   org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry.register@138:  HHH000270: Type
>   registration [[Ljava.lang.Byte;] overrides previous :
>   org.hibernate.type.WrapperBinaryType@638977e0
>   o.h.t.s.e.i.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.processGetTableResults@377:
>   HHH000263: More than one table found: t_agent
>   o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper.logPersistenceUnitInformation@31:
>   HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
>           name: defaultPersistenceUnit

Comment: Maybe you have duplicated @Table(name=t_agent) annotations?

Comment: can you show how you use mapping entity to db table ( @Table) ?

Comment: Take a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36907095/more-than-one-table-found-in-namespace-schemaextractionexception

Comment: can you show how you use mapping entity to db table ( @Table) ? probably you already have tagent table it database and your entity called TAgent and you didn't specify t_agent in @Table . hibernate treys to match it

Comment: @Entity
@Table(name = "t_agent")

Comment: i am using a clean database schema. no duplicated table name is there.

Answer (score 2):

Recently i faced similar problem, it was due to the hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property value "update". Remove of comment this property if possible. This is not the best solution but it works for me

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
<property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="myuser"/>
```

in persitence.xml solved the problem.